# Полимормизм с Абстракцией в PHP ООП

Tags: php, mysql, ооп

Добрый день друзья возникла проблема с выводом информации из баз данных. Подскажите как можно решить задачу.Заранне спасибо 
Вот код классов

```
include 'db.php';

abstract class Example
{
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $age;
    public $city;
    public $country;


    function __construct()
    {
        $this->firstname=$info['firstname'];
        $this->lastname=$info['lastname'];
        $this->age=$info['age'];
        $this->city=$info['city'];
        $this->country=$info['country'];
    }

   abstract function GetInfo();
}

class First  extends Example
{

  function GetInfo()
  {
    print "Your Name Is : \n" . $this->firstname . "<br>";
    print "Your Lastname Is : \n" . $this->lastname . "<br>";
  }

}

$first = new First;
print $first->GetInfo();

class Second  extends Example
{

  function GetInfo()
  {
    print "Your Age Is : \n" . $this->age . "<br>";
    print "Your City Is : \n" . $this->city . "<br>";
    print "Your Country Is : \n" . $this->country . "<br>";
  }

}

$second = new Second;
print $second->GetInfo();
```

Код Баз Данных  db.php

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "website";

$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname , $username , $password , $database);

if(!$connection)
{
  die("No Connection" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql='SELECT * FROM `info`';
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $info[]=$row;
    }

    return $info;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На return info выполнение прерывается, уберите эту строчку. Info нужно передавать в конструктор параметром. Использовать глобальные переменные очень плохо с точки зрения архитектуры и ооп.
в db.php:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $info[]=$row;
    }

    //return $info; убираем эту строку
}
```

В колассе Example:

```
function __construct($info)
{
    $this->firstname=$info['firstname'];
    $this->lastname=$info['lastname'];
    $this->age=$info['age'];
    $this->city=$info['city'];
    $this->country=$info['country'];
}
```

При создании экземпляров передаем в конструктор $info^

```
$first = new First($info);
$second = new Second($info);
```

Comment: Я могу исползовать статические классы для решения задач . Но какой будет решения для таково кода.

Comment: Статические классы в общем тоже плохо. Но это к данному вопросу не относится уже.